# How to store output from %in% as an if true, X, if false, Y

Tags: r, logic

I quite frequently need to match the rownames from two matrices and store the output as a list of hit/no hit in another list. I have taken to looping through my lists of rownames running if statements and storing the output by appending to the end of the list but there must be a simple, elegant solution that I am missing.

> test <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) %in% c(1,4,5,6,7)
>
> test
> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

How would I store the TRUE as e.g. "red" and the FALSE as e.g. "green" so that:

> test
> [1] "red" "green" "green" "red" "red" "red" "red"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `test <- ifelse(test, 'red', 'green')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **ifelse**:

```
test <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) %in% c(1,4,5,6,7)
ifelse(test, "red", "green")
```

Comment: Ha, thanks. I should definitely have thought of that!